# How to find every elements from Parent in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, linq

here i want to validate few textboxes by Element Finding on button Click event

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var button = (Button) sender;

        // button Parent
        var stackPanel = button.Parent as StackPanel;

        // button Parent > parent
        var parentStackPanel = stackPanel.Parent as StackPanel;

        // button Parent > parent > Children
        var childStackPanel = parentStackPanel.Children.Where(a => a is StackPanel).FirstOrDefault() as StackPanel;

        // button Parent > parent > Children >Elements
        var textBox = childStackPanel.Children.Where(a => a is TextBox).FirstOrDefault() as TextBox;
        var image = childStackPanel.Children.Where(a => a is Image).FirstOrDefault() as Image;

        if (textBox.Text == "") image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/Others/TickWrong.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

    }
```

the problem is I only able to find First element due to FirstOrDefault()

```
var childStackPanel = parentStackPanel.Children.Where(a => a is StackPanel).FirstOrDefault() as StackPanel;
```

is there any possible way to find all the elements  .
by Array or something??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove FirstOrDefault.

```
var childStackPanels = parentStackPanel.Children.Where(a => a is StackPanel);
```

This will return an `IEnumerable<T>` which you can iterate upon.

To get a list you can use `ToList()` extension method of `IEnumerable<T>`

Answer (score 0):

Add the `VisualTreeEnumeration` class from this [blog](http://geekswithblogs.net/codingbloke/archive/2010/12/19/visual-tree-enumeration.aspx) to your project.  This gives you a couple of extension methods on a `DependencyObject` that uses the `VisualTreeHelper` to find elements.  With that in place you can enumerate the `TextBox` controls with:-

```
 foreach (var txt in this.Descendents().OfType<TextBox>())
 {
     // Do something with each TextBox found.
 }
```